# How to do math operations with floats and integers in C

Tags: c

Why is the value of x not changing

How do you use a fraction with an integer in c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x , y , n=0;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    scanf("%d", &y);
    printf("%d %d\n",x , y);
        
    x = (13/12) * x;
    printf("%d\n", x );

}
```

Comment: `13/12` is an *integer division* and its value is 1. Try `x = (13.0/12) * x;`. Note that `x` is also an integer value and the result will be truncated. Try with large enough value like `x = 1000`.

Comment: Another way (avoiding floating-point calculation) is `x = 13 * x / 12;`

Comment: @MikeCAT:  Doing `13*x/12` will not round properly.  Example: `13 * 7 / 12`, the exact answer is `7.58`, which should properly round to `8`. But your formula will truncate to `7`.

Comment: @abelenky It is unclear that the result should be truncated or rounded.